# R shiny: rpivottable, how to make a reactive table from it

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, rpivottable

I have a rpivottable but from that pivottable output table I want to make a table. And when I change the filters in the pivottable it should change the other table i.e reactive.

I have a rpivottable but from that pivottable output table I want to make a table. And when I change the filters in the pivottable it should change the other table i.e reactive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could use `rpivottable` or you can use [the React pivottable.js](https://codeburst.io/introducing-react-pivottable-4bfdd511afed). I'm not sure that there is even close to enough information here for someone to offer an answer.